# Do we need to do Consumer Driven Contract Testing Kafka Driven Micro-services when we have the Scheme Registry?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry, pact, spring-cloud-contract

I am trying to understand if the concept of Consumer-Driven Contracts ( [CDC](https://martinfowler.com/articles/consumerDrivenContracts.html) ) is still valid in the context of Kafka based Event Driven Architecture.

In the RESTful world, Consumer-Driven Contract verification is vital, because there is no concept of schema evolution based compatibility testing that happens at runtime. A bad producer may be free to change the schema and deploy without notifying consumers and if the APIs are not versioned properly, that may break your consumers if the producer hasn't paid attention to the consumer patterns. So the concept of CDC provides the best way in my opinion to ensure that producers stay consumer compliant as they evolve their schemas.

Now, focusing on the Kafka based EDA, the concept of Schema Registry plays a bigger role in consumer - producer relationships. It acts as the coordinator between consumers and producers helping to evolve schemas with a level of compatibility you desire so that producers won't break consumers or at least it has been made very difficult to do so. With that trust in place, I am trying to understand if the concept of CDC is still applicable for Kafka / Schema Registry driven micro-service architectures?

Referring: https://docs.confluent.io/cloud/current/client-apps/testing.html#schema-management-and-evolution

> After your applications are running in production, schemas may evolve but still need to be compatible for all applications that rely on both old and new versions of a schema. Confluent Schema Registry allows for schema evolution and provides compatibility checks to ensure that the contract between producers and consumers is not broken."""

**Update:** Further more, In Kafka, we mostly use Avro like Schema Oriented Serialization formats, it seems the support within the Contract Testing Frameworks for such formats is limited too.

- https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-jvm/issues/603
- [Spring cloud contract tests for avro messages using Schema Registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66654842/spring-cloud-contract-tests-for-avro-messages-using-schema-registry)

Comment: Isn't this only testing the schema? With cdc you're evolving the api in such a way that consumers only use what they need to know about in the message. You don't really care about the whole message but only the subset of it. Also you can check whether you're sending a message to the proper topic / queue. I'm not familiar with how this schema registry works so maybe it does answer all of your conserns

Comment: Thanks @MarcinGrzejszczak for your comment. I agree 100% to what you said about schema compatibility. It does not test whether the producer schema is adhering to consumer expectations which is what Consumer Driven Contracts like testing strategies provide us.

Comment: However, when you have strict schema compatibility rules set on producer contracts by the schema registry, I think the Producer Driven Contract Testing may be more applicable in this scenario. So it can abide to schema as well as evolve without breaking expectations.

Comment: Yes producer driven contract makes more sense. Still i can be unaware of how to properly use the messages cause i just have the schema

Answer (score 1):

By default, sure, but the registry checks can be disabled or reversed such that only forward changes are compatible, not including backwards compatible

It's still recommended to do unit testing on your consumer apps for expected inputs from producers, regardless of a gate-keeping registry (which is not a required property for any producer)

Comment: Appreciate your comment. Definitely I agree that consumers needs to test on their side based on producer inputs. My question was on "Consumer Driven Contract Testing" which actually happens on the Producer End. If a producer is Schema Registry compliant for backward/forward compatibility, does it still need to do CDC Testing is the question I have (and what we are trying to achieve by doing in addition to schema registry usage)

Comment: From the Producer, you can use the Schema Registry maven plugin  for example, or it's validate api endpoint (both over HTTP) to check the updated schema is compatible. That is, assuming you weren't able to call the internal java APIs that do the same. I wouldn't package and deploy a new producer app/schema change without testing at least that.

Answer (score 1):

Schema Registry when used properly "guarantees" that the consumer can de-serialise the message that the producer serialised. That is all.

"Producer driven contract (PDC) testing" should be viewed as an extra semantic layer, that when used properly "guarantees" that the consumer actually "understands" the de-serilised message and can react appropriately (e.g. deliver business value).

If you think about it, if you do proper contract testing, you do not need avro schema evolution at all. As the consumer contract tests will drive which fields are necessary or not. If no consumer needs a field (i.e. no consumer contract test fails), then a message field can be deleted by the producer. Still you have to make consumers flexible to be able to deserialise every (e.g. json) message from "beginning of time", if you keep events forever though and you want to be able to read from offset 0.

Especially if you are doing event-based microservices that emit/ consume Avro events, then I do not see any safe way to deploy your microservices independently just by using a Schema Registry and without doing PDC. Usually companies end up building a distributed monolith that all services are released at the same time and tested via time consuming integration tests. Or just release and deploy the service that changed, but still do time consuming integration tests.

EDIT:
In my case I ended up adding support for Avro based contracts. Take a look here: [github.com/vspiliop/kafka-contract-test-producer](https://github.com/vspiliop/kafka-contract-test-producer) and https://github.com/vspiliop/kafka-contract-test-consumer